# "На конструктор по умолчанию для [название_структуры] нельзя ссылаться, так как эта функция удалена"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, классы, visual-c++, объединение

Имеется структура `books` которая исполняет роль каталога. В неё вложен `union books_type`, в который, в свою очередь, вложены ещё 2 структуры `book` и `magazine` для книги и журнала соответственно.

Вот код:

```
struct books {
string name;
int year;
int pages;

    union books_type {
        struct book {
            string author;
        } book;
        struct magazine{
            string redaction;
            int articles;
        } magazine;
    } books_type;
};
```

При попытке определить массив структур:

```
books* b = new books[MAX];
```

Visual studio выдаёт ошибку `на конструктор по умолчанию для "books" нельзя ссылаться, так как эта функция удалена`

Что в таком случае делать?

Comment: `std::string` внутри `union` гарантирует вам проблемы. (Нужно вручную вызывать конструкторы и деструкторы...) Возмите `std::variant` вместо `union` и не мучайтесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для объединения компилятор не умеет генерировать ни конструктор по умолчанию, ни деструктор.

Напишите их сами - и все получится.

```
union books_type {
books_type(){}
~books_type(){}
    struct book {
        string author;
    } book;
    struct magazine{
        string redaction;
        int articles;
    } magazine;
} books_type;
```

и ваш код уже будет компилироваться; конечно, лучше бы определить семантически разумные конструктор и деструктор, а не пустые...

Если, конечно, вам вообще требуется объединение. Потому что проблем в этом случае куда больше, чем решений... :(